# Amazon Product Advertising API return 503 (Service Unavailable) too often

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle, amazon-product-api

I have written myself a little PHP Script which is fetching products from the Amazon Product Advertising API. To do this I am using PHP Laravel 5.5, the [Apai-IO Library](https://github.com/rezzafr33/apaiio-laravel) and [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle).

I also do track all my request and in my opinion there are way too many 503 (Service Unavailable) returns from Amazons API.. Cause as it is saying [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/TroubleshootingApplications.html) I do have 8640 requests per day and a maximum of 1 request per second.

My script gets ran by a cronjob every 15 Minutes all day long. So, my scripts starts 96 times a day. However, I have some validations running on the returned product. If the validation is approving the returned product, the cronjob is done. If not, the script will try to request a new product with a spacing time in between the new request and the last request of 5 seconds. But this also means, I could do 90 requests per cronjob cause 96 times 90 is equal to the maximum request limit of 8640 per day.

However, my request limit is far below the request limit. It somewhere around 2000-3000 requests per day. And that is what is confusing me. I don't get, why the Amazon Product Advertising API is returning a 503 (Service Unavailable) when I have a spacing time of at least 5 seconds per request and my daily requests are far below the limit...

This is an example of the error I get when the API is returning a 503 request:

```
2019-01-23 08:28:05 - Error fetching Amazon product from API Server error: `GET http://webservices.amazon.de/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=00000000000000000000&AssociateTag=my_tag-21&ItemId=B00UIAK6D8&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Large&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2019-01-23T07%3A28%3A05Z&Version=2013-08-01&Signature=69eB66yi6zQu6IhCHj2sk0FJznfN3g169D2Ng8TKnz8%3D` resulted in a `503 Service Unavailable` response:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ItemLookupErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-08-01/"><Error><Code>RequestThro (truncated...)
```

I can provide you guys also some code if you would like to.. But I don't think this is really necessary?
Cause I am pretty sure there is a pause of at least 5 seconds per request cause I am using `sleep(5);` and thats why I am more then pretty sure there is a pause of at least 5 seconds per request!

Would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: I have a similar problem, this has something to do with the rate limiting of Amazon. You will have to catch this error and queue it again. That is what I did.

Comment: That is what I am doing. But I would like to have one request per second cause I need more requests..

Comment: I ran into this as well. Perhaps something changed with the rate limiting. All requests are returning 503.

Comment: Hey there - it looks related to this policy change about throttling that went in effect 1/23.  I found this forum where it's a common issue and shouldn't be being applied to many accounts https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=298518&tstart=0